# How to Supply Default Value in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, default-value

I need to find a way to supply a default value if the user leaves a cell blank in my datagridview. Right now I'm able to display an error message if the user leaves the cell blank but I also want to insert a default text in the cell after the message pops up. For example if the cell requires a name and the user leaves it blank, a message will pop up and tell the user that he/she cannot leave the name blank. After this I want the text "name" to populate the cell

```
If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then 'checking numeric value for column 1 only
Dim cellData = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value
 if cellData Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(cellData) OrElse cellData.ToString = String.Empty Then       
   MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Value")
   Exit Sub
```

End If

Comment: What about putting a `DefaultValue` into the `DataColumn` in question?  Then it is handled for you when a new row is added to the table.

Comment: The cell in question already has a value when the program opens. This program is pulling data from an excel file. I just want to supply a default value after the message pops up.

Comment: I think you're close to coming up with the answer, however "DefaultValue" is not a member of DataGridView Column, so what do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: I was referring to the `DataTable` not the `DataGridView` [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue.aspx).  I made an assumption about the datastore backing your grid.  Does this work? `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "default value"`

Comment: Glad to hear that did it.  I posted it as an Answer so that you can mark that it was what you needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).Value = "default value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a default value into DatagridView empty cell:

```
For k As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    For l = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1

        Dim cellData = DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells(l).Value
        If cellData Is Nothing OrElse IsDBNull(cellData) OrElse cellData.ToString = String.Empty Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(k).Cells(l).Value = "0"
        End If

    Next

Next
```